# ASP.NET 5 - Multiple [FromQuery] attribute for same property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

We want to add multiple [FromQuery] attributes to the same property e.g.:

```
public class SampleQueryRequestModel
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "ProductId"] // deprecated this way
    [FromQuery(Name = "Product.Id"]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

So that both requests map to the ProductId property:

```
/api/books?productId=123    // to maintain backward compatibility 

/api/books?product.id=123
```

Is it possible using `FromQuery` attribute or we have to create another property and use set;get; to handle this?

Comment: Looks like [api versioning](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/your-guide-rest-api-versioning-aspnet-core) is what could be useful for you

Comment: I think you'd also queried for solution on it but failed, and me too. In my opinion, when we can't use an easy way to achieve your requirement, why not just add a new property as you said above. We may rewrite the attribute method, we may add a filter to rewrite the incoming http context request and some other actions. But they are all more complex then just adding a property...